# Controlling a urdf model on Gazebo unsing pr2_mechanism package

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a urdf robot model that I want to simulate and control on gazebo. I need to know if I can use the pr2_mechanism package to control my robot on the gazebo.

If I can can I simply follow the tutorials given in the ROS tutorials ? If now what are the what should I using ?

Can I use the following tutorial and apply it for a joint that I want to control and see it on Gazebo :

http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorial/Writing%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller

http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Running%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller

If not what tutorials must I follow for me to create a controller for my robot ?

I do not find enough document to follow things around, can someone please explain .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1358/controlling-a-urdf-model-on-gazebo-unsing-pr2_mechanism-package/) by [Bharadwaj Ramesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/154/bharadwaj-ramesh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I think the Gazebo part from those tutorials are outdated, [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1334/resources-for-writing-ros-plugins/) is a similar question with an accepted answer to it, maybe it can help you.

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0